# Revisar si una fecha es valida en calendario MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Necesito hacer una revisión de la información que ingresa a la base de datos mediante un script `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` y estoy validando algunos campos con un *`trigger after insert`* (porque es una tabla 'sucia' que solo coloca información y despues vuelco la informacion correcta en otra tabla), la cuestion es que tengo un campo de tipo **DATE (Y-m-d)** que si ingreso una fecha inexistente (Ej: 2023-09-31) arroja el error

> Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect date value:
> '2023-09-31'

He intentado *"cachar"* el error dentro del mismo trigger pero me es imposible debido a que solo consigo que se envie el error a mi frontend.

Les dejo una parte del trigger con el que estoy intentando *cachar* el error:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `dirty_si_base_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `dirty_si_base_AFTER_INSERT` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

[...]
DECLARE fecha_valida_notificacion BOOLEAN;



    [...]
    
     -- Verificamos si la fecha fallo es válida
     
   SET fecha_valida_notificacion = (
      STR_TO_DATE(NEW.fecha_fallo_notificacion, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NOT NULL AND 
    STR_TO_DATE(NEW.fecha_fallo_notificacion, '%Y-%m-%d') = NEW.fecha_fallo_notificacion
   );

    -- Si la fecha no es válida, ingresamos a la tabla de errores 
   IF NOT fecha_valida_notificacion THEN
        insert into errores_carga(con, mensaje, campo, archivo, created_at)
        values (cast(new.id  as char), 'La fecha no existe', 5, 'SI', now());
   END IF;
   
END
```

Comment: El tipo `DATE` y el tipo `DATETIME` no son intercambiables. El error indica que estás tratando de guardar un dato tipo `DATE` en un campo declarado como `DATETIME`. Debes buscar una forma de hacer el `CAST` apropiado.

Comment: No, la cuestion no es el cast de los datos, es el ingreso de fechas inexistentes como lo puse en el ejemplo

Comment: Esta fecha no es válida: `2023-09-31`, comprenderás por qué: **el mes de septiembre tiene un máximo de 30 días**. Lo que deberías preguntarte es qué fallo hay en tu sistema que está permitiendo que se generen fechas inválidas. Ese es el problema que deberías resolver. Si es una normalización, podrías por ejemplo manejar los casos de error, insertando algún identificador en una tabla para luego corregir esos registros erróneos que tienes en tu archivo. Pero no deberías dejarlo así, sino corregir el error en la raíz.

Comment: @A. Cedano Mi sistema no genera fechas invalidas y no me es posible corregir en la raiz debido a que lo que se busca es justamente eso errores en raiz para poder corregirlos.

Comment: `2023-09-31` es una fecha inválida, por lo ya dicho. El mensaje de error es claro: *`incorrect date value: '2023-09-31'`*. Por tanto, se está generando una fecha así en alguna parte. Debes detectar dónde y corregir el código o lo que sea que la está generando. Si el código fuente donde se generan los `.csv` no está a tu alcance, entonces, como ya dije, debes implementar una estrategia en tu código que bloquee ese código erróneo y quizá inserte un identificador en una tabla para comunicar esos errores a los responsables de aquel código o lo que sea. Negar la evidencia no resolverá el problema.

Comment: Estimado, si lees con detenimiento la pregunta te darás cuenta que lo que expones es lo mismo que esta planteado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despues de hacer una investigación y revisiones en documentación de MySQL llegué a la conclusion de que en efecto STR_TO_DATE() solo verifica por rangos individuales, es decir que el año este en el rango ( 0-9999), Mes en rango (1-12) y día rango (1-31) al contrario que al hacer un CAST que verifica la integridad de la fecha.

Les dejo el codigo de como se solucionó

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `dirty_si_base_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `dirty_si_base_AFTER_INSERT` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

[...]
DECLARE fecha_valida_notificacion BOOLEAN;



    [...]
    
     -- Verificamos si la fecha fallo es válida
    IF CAST(new.fecha_fallo_notificacion as DATE) is NULL then
        insert into errores_carga(con, mensaje, campo, archivo, created_at)
        values (cast(new.id  as char), 'La fecha no existe ', 5, 'SICOPU', now());
    end if;
END
```